# constexpr + multidimension array fails

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, constexpr

I'm having difficulties understanding constexpr in the context of a C++ builtin multi-dimensional array.  The example below illustrates my problem.

a) Looking a value at compile time works as I expect as long as I don't assign it to anything.

b) But if I try to assign it to another constexpr variable, I get a compile time error.

I've looked around and even checked the standards document.  Anyone who can explain this to me is truly a guru.  FWIW, I'm compiling this with CLang 8.1 under Xcode with C++14 enabled.

```
using uint8_t = unsigned char;


#if 1
enum class safe_numerics_error : uint8_t {
    success = 0,
    failure,    // result is above representational maximum
    error_count
};
#else
// avoiding enum class fails to solve problem
struct safe_numerics_error {
    const uint8_t m_t;
    constexpr const static uint8_t success = 0;
    constexpr const static uint8_t failure = 1;
    constexpr safe_numerics_error(uint8_t t) :
        m_t(t)
    {}
    constexpr operator uint8_t () const {
        return m_t;
    }
};
#endif

template<typename R>
struct checked_result {
    const safe_numerics_error m_e;
    const union {
        const R m_r;
        char const * const m_msg;
    };
    constexpr /*explicit*/ checked_result(const R & r) :
        m_e(safe_numerics_error::success),
        m_r(r)
    {}
    constexpr /*explicit*/ checked_result(const safe_numerics_error & e) :
        m_e(e),
        m_msg("")
    {}
};

// integers addition
template<class T>
constexpr inline checked_result<T> operator+(
    const checked_result<T> & t,
    const checked_result<T> & u
){
    // "Constexpr variable 'e' must be initialized by a constant expression"
    constexpr const safe_numerics_error x[2][2]{
        // t == success
        {
            // u == ...
            safe_numerics_error::success,
            safe_numerics_error::failure
        },
        // t == positive_overflow_error,
        {
            // u == ...
            safe_numerics_error::failure,
            safe_numerics_error::failure
        }
    };

#if 1  // compile fails
    constexpr const safe_numerics_error e = x
        [static_cast<uint8_t>(t.m_e)]
        [static_cast<uint8_t>(u.m_e)]
    ;

    return
        (safe_numerics_error::success == e)
        ? t.m_r + u.m_r
        : checked_result<T>(e)
    ;
#else  // works as expected
    return
        safe_numerics_error::success == x
            [static_cast<uint8_t>(t.m_e)]
            [static_cast<uint8_t>(u.m_e)]
        ? t.m_r + u.m_r
        : checked_result<T>(x
            [static_cast<uint8_t>(t.m_e)]
            [static_cast<uint8_t>(u.m_e)]
        )
    ;
#endif
}

int main(){
    constexpr const checked_result<unsigned> i = 0;
    constexpr const checked_result<unsigned> j = 0;

    constexpr const checked_result<unsigned> k = i + j;

    // return k.m_r;

    constexpr const checked_result<unsigned> i2 = safe_numerics_error::failure;
    constexpr const checked_result<unsigned> j2 = 0;

    constexpr const checked_result<unsigned> k2 = i2 + j2;
    return k2.m_r;
}
```

Comment: what is the error? in which line?

Comment: is the code that your compiler wont see (in the `#else` blocks) just noise or part of the question?

Comment: Two comments on this: 1) you're returning m_r at the end of main in the error case, which is invalid since that object is constructed with an error 2) why not just & the enum values instead of using a 2D array? i.e. success & success == success, but failure & anything = failure

Comment: Oh another one: constexpr variables are inherently const, so you don't have to re-specify that.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you can't initialize a `constexpr` variable

```
constexpr const safe_numerics_error e = x
    [static_cast<uint8_t>(t.m_e)]
    [static_cast<uint8_t>(u.m_e)]
```

with a value that depend from an argument of a function (or method) (as `t` and `u`).

I know that your `operator+()` is a `constexpr` one and that in your example you use it only to initialize `constexpr` values.

But a `constexpr` function/method can be used compile-time *and* run-time. So a compiler can't accept code, in a `constexpr` function/method, that can't be executed run-time.

Comment: This answer sums it up, but to clarify: e is declared constexpr no matter what, but if the function isn't called with constexpr arguments then that variable can't be constexpr. If you just declare e const, it should still be evaluated at compile time with constexpr arguments but won't error.

Comment: @budjmt - not sure to understand what you mean but also if you declare `e` `const` (like in the question) the function can be called with a non-cont value; so the compiler can't accept that is used to initialize a `constexpr` variable (anyway: I don't see the usefulness in declaring `constexpr` a variable (depending from an input parameter) in a `constexpr` function: if the function is executed compile time, the variable is initialized compile time also if isn't declared `constexpr`.

Comment: exactly, it should just be `const safe_numerics_error e = ...;` I just meant it should *only* be const, not constexpr const. e isn't inherently constexpr, it's only constexpr at compile time.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  That is, one needs to remove the "constexpr " term in order for this to work - even it's its only called at compile timer with constexpr arguments.  Good  job, this clarified it for me.